# How to avoid Visual Studio auto expanding all custom controls

Tags: c#, visual-studio, windows-forms-designer

At the first time that I open the Designer toolbox on Visual Studio (VS) it expand all my projects custom controls. I need to collapse one by one. This is really annoying. VS should remember at the .suo that I've already collapsed all before.

Is there a way I can prevent this behavior without removing the custom controls from the toolbox?

Answer (score 2):

Here is a workaround.

Click one of the toolbox item and press "/" button on the numeric side of your keyboard (right above the "8" button). It should keep the items from expanding.

Depending on the numbers of your custom controls, you may need to click it multiple times. (It is less painful than having to scroll through them).

Shortcuts:

- / = collapse toolbox
- * = expand toolbox

Comment: Thanks for the workaround. I'm still hoping for a solution. :)